# How to assign model property to the additionalViewData in EditorFor in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

The goal of my work is to disable the text box on a web page if condition1 is met.

So I created a view template called DoubleTemplate

```
@model double

@if (ViewData["IsVisible"] != null)
{
    var IsVisible = (bool)ViewData["Switcher"];

    if (IsVisible)
    { 
        @Html.TextBox(string.Empty,Model)
    }
}
```

And back to my web page, here is my code to call this template

```
@Html.EditorFor(m =>  m.Year1Data, "DoubleTemplate", new {Switcher = m.CurrentProgramYear == 1})
```

An error under the second m saying:

> The name 'm' does not exist in the current context

So my question is how to assign my model property to the additionalViewData in EditorFor

Btw, here is the syntax of EnditorFor on MSDN

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression,
    string templateName,
    Object additionalViewData
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `CurrentProgramYear` is a property in you model, change

```
.... new {Switcher = m.CurrentProgramYear ...
```

to

```
.... new {Switcher = Model.CurrentProgramYear ...
```

Comment: Hi @Stephen, it works now :) thx. However, if the code(on the web page) was in a loop and the property I need is in an instance of MyViewModel which is in a collection of MyViewModel(let's call it MyList), then in this case, I wouldn't be able to use Model, how can we solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - you will need to post a bit more of the view including the loop. But why would you do it like this as opposed to a simple `@if(Model.CurrentProgramYear == 1) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m =>  m.Year1Data) }`?

Comment: Hi Stephen, because I have more than 50 similar code sections on the same page which are under different conditions to show/hide. So I choose to use View Temple. but nvm, I tried my assumed scenario and found it doesn't make sense. so we can ignore that. thanks :)